# Delete with a subquery MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to delele with a subquery that is the same table 'carretilla'
This works in SQL Server

```
DELETE FROM carretilla 
WHERE carcod IN (
  SELECT carcod  
  FROM carretilla 
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,carfch, NOW()) > 10 
  group BY carcod
);
```

How can i do it?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't reference the table you delete from or update directly, but if you use a subquery the server will create a temporary record set and let you do the delete, so this should work:

```
DELETE FROM carretilla 
WHERE carcod IN (
  SELECT carcod FROM (
    SELECT carcod  FROM carretilla 
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,carfch, NOW()) > 10 group BY carcod
  ) temp_table
);
```

See this [sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47baa/1).

Comment: ERROR: 1175 you are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table

Comment: That means that your MySQL server is running in safemode and you are forced to delete by primary key(id). In other words you have to run the subquery first, and then loop throught all the results deleting one at a time.

Comment: I'm guessing `carcod` isn't the primary key? You might be able to get around this if you do `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` I don't know if would recommend it though. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates for more info.

Comment: You can also do the trick of `AND [primary_key] != [a value it never actually could]`